# ParserError: Source "contracts/Token.sol" not found: File import callback not supported

Tags: solidity, truffle

I have problem when I use *truffle test*. I seperated files used in contract with Solidity framework and I can't compile my code(see below). When code is not seperated works fine.

I tried reinstall truffle again but doesn't help for me. I'm using ubuntu but on mac its working! - so I suppose maybe problem is in *case-sensitive*.

```
contracts/Contract.sol:7:1: ParserError: Source "contracts/Token.sol" not found: File import callback not supported
import './Token.sol' as Token;
^------------------------------------------^
Compiliation failed. See above.
```

I read [Solidity source file page](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/layout-of-source-files.html) and [File import callback not supported](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/issues/402)